# Infowindow not displaying image

Tags: javascript, asp.net, infowindow

I am using google maps and want to display an image in infowindow which is fetched from database but instead of image it displays an image file name(for example edit.png). But how to get the image.

I am getting the path of image but image is not displaying.Plese give me the solution its urgent.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Show/Add multiple markers to Google Maps from database in asp.net website
</title>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5- 
 2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
function initialize() {
         $.ajax
         ({ 
            type:'POST',
            url: 'MapDetais.aspx',
            data:'{}',
            dataType: 'json',
            async:false,
            success: function(data)
                {
                        for (var markers = 0; markers < data.length; markers++)
                        {
                            var name=data[markers].Name;
                            var lon=data[markers].Longitude;
                            var lat=data[markers].Latitude;
                            var desc=data[markers].Description;
                            var photo=data[markers].Photo;
                        }
                               var mapOptions =
                                {
                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].Latitude,data[0].Longitude),
                                zoom: 8,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                }
                               debugger
                               var infoWindow;
                                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  
  mapOptions);

                                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                var data1 = data[i]
                                var imgMarker= new Image();
                                imgMarker.src=data1.Photo;
                                var IMG=imgMarker.src; 

                                //imgMarker.src=data1.Photo;
                                //document.body.appendChild(imgMarker.src);
                                 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data1.Latitude, data1.Longitude);
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatlng,
                                map: map

                                });
                                 var contentString='<div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;        
  font-weight:bold; color:#FF0000; font-size:12px">'
                                +data1.Name+" </div></br> <div>"+data1.Description+"</div> </br><div  
 align='center'>"+IMG+"</div></br>";
                                 infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
                                ({
                                 content:contentString,
                                 width:200,
                                 height:100
                                });
                                infoWindow.open(map,marker);

                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                });
                        }
                 }
          })
        }
</script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the image is inside a html img tag?  I think you'll need to give us more info or an example.